# What are these planes and what are they doing?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

I know next to nothing about planes, so excuse any naivety below…

I live in Denver CO and frequently see military planes in what look to be training exercises. Today I saw two pairs of planes (one "big" and one "fighter") flying really close and am curious if the planes and/or exercise are identifiable. One pair disappeared behind the building before I could get a picture of both, so attached is just a picture of the trailing pair.

[image]

Comment: Mommy, what's that plane doing with that other plane?

Comment: If this is happening low enough that you can easily notice it from the ground and snap a clear photo (assuming you are not a news reporter or bird watcher etc who regularly carries around a camera with a long telephoto lens), it is probably being done for the benefit of people on the ground (air show, stadium flyover, etc) or as a rehearsal for such activities.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The larger airplane is a Boeing KC-135 Air Refueling jet and the smaller jet behind is being refueled.

[image]

(Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-135_Stratotanker))

Comment: Ah thanks! Must be this https://www.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/3438220/amc-celebrates-100th-year-of-air-refueling-with-community-flyovers-across-the-us/

Comment: Today's refuelings might be only simulations, without fuel flowing.  That's how EAA Airventure Oshkosh did it a few years ago.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, I'm curious, what makes you think this?

Comment: Mainly because Oshkosh chose that.  Also, for them and for today, less risk, less expense (an empty tanker is lighter and thus burns less fuel itself), and the "refuelee" doesn't actually need more fuel.

Comment: I mean for an airshow I agree that a full load of gas in the tanker and topping off receivers is completely unnecessary, but if you are near a military base, and they are doing it for training, it is pretty standard practice to take a sip and check that systems are functional.

Comment: @MichaelHall I would think that testing out the system can be done on the ground without rolling it simultaneously into a training exercise. If they actually transfer fuel and someone makes a mistake, both planes can go up in flames and then they get to fall onto residential areas...

Comment: @Nelson, some checks can be performed on ground, but you really can't get a full system check.  Anyway, if you are getting practice dry plugs already there really isn't any additional hazard in transferring some fuel.  It is a far safer process than you putting gas in your car.

Comment: @MichaelHall I've seen people drive off with the nozzle attached and nobody died... you're saying that the plane can fly off with the nozzle attached and everything would be fine?

Comment: @Nelson:  https://theaviationgeekclub.com/that-time-a-u-s-navy-f-a-18-hornet-landed-safely-with-a-kc-10-refueling-basket-stuck-in-its-refueling-probe/

Comment: That's _probably_ pretty minor, @MichaelHall, compared to the various bombers that returned with combat damage during WWII. Amazing what an aircraft can [take](https://theaviationist.com/2021/01/11/that-time-a-b-52h-stratofortress-bomber-lost-its-tail-over-new-mexico-but-managed-to-land-6-hours-later/) and still [return home](https://theaviationist.com/2014/09/15/f-15-lands-with-one-wing/) (for more modern examples).

Comment: @Nelson In the entire history of the US military's use of mid-air refueling planes, only one plane has ever been destroyed, and it was due to a ground maintenance accident, not during a refueling.  It's not as dangerous as you seem to think.

Comment: @Nelson There's never an "attachment"; the fuel intake probe makes positive contact with the outlet in the center of the basket. The flexible fuel hose, plus drag on the basket, allows for a solid connection as long as the plane's positioned within a couple of meters of nominal. And the system is designed to fail safe (by passively disconnecting, or at worst by breaking at designated breaking points) if things get out of position.

Comment: Since @oll30 notes that they "know next to nothing about planes", we should also mention that this activity (aerial refueling hookup) happens all the time, to the point of being a routine part of flying the planes (which is the point). We just don't usually see it because it's normally done at cruising altitude and in unpopulated areas. The only thing unusual here is they're doing it relatively low over cities as a PR demonstration.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Incorrect, there was one. The 1966 B-52-KC-135 collision over Palomares Spain resulted in the loss of both aircraft. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_Palomares_B-52_crash. The recovery of one of the B28 bombs was in the movie 'Men Of Honor'. And I was at Barksdale when the lone KC-10 incident happened. We felt/heard the "boom" over a mile away.

Comment: @WPNSGuy Palomares wasn't even the only refueling gone horribly wrong (although it certainly is the most well-known). Wikipedia lists [two more refueling collisions of B-52s alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress#Notable_accidents) (in 1959 and 1960, just search the page for "KC-135").

Comment: Just at a cursory search for air to air refueling crashes, a F35 crashed in Sept 2020, a F18 and C130 crashed into each other in 2018. Seems like an entirely untrue statement, @darrelhoffman.

Comment: @Sneftel, the way you describe it is a bit misleading. In the probe and drogue system you have to hit the basket with 2-3 knots of closure to snap the spring loaded rollers in the basket over the lip on the probe to ensure positive engagement in the detent and create a positive connection to prevent fuel leaking out. And there’s nothing “passive” about disengaging either.